# helm and kubectl context mismatch

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, microk8s

I'm having trouble understanding `helm`'s use of `helm --kube-context=microk8s install ...` should install into the context `microk8s` thus into my local microk8s cluster rather than the remote GKE cluster which I once connected to.

This however fails due to `Error: could not get Kubernetes config for context "microk8s": context "microk8s" does not exist` if I run e.g. `helm --kube-context=microk8s install --name mereet-kafka` after successfully running `helm init` and adding necessary repositories.

The context `microk8s` is present and enabled according to `kubectl config current-context`. I can even reproduce this by running `helm --kube-context=$(kubectl config current-context) install --name mereet-kafka` in order to avoid any typos.

Why can't `helm` use obviously present contexts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like a kubernetes configuration problem more than an issue with helm itself.

There are few things that might help:

1. Check the config file in `~/.kube/config`

   - `kubectl config view`

Is `current-context` set to: microk8s?

2. Try to use:

   - `kubectl config get-contexts`
   - `kubectl config set-context`
   - `kubectl config use-context`

with proper arguments `--server` `--user` `--cluster`

3. Check if you are refering to the config from `~/.kube/config` and not your own private config from somewhere else.
4. Check if you have a `KUBECONFIG` environment variable (`echo $KUBECONFIG`)

I hope it helps.