# Authentication Issue: GitLab CI/CD Job fails when it runs "kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci

I get this error: `forbidden: User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/openapi/v2": No policy matched.`

It seems to happen here:

```
I0302 15:57:33.593662      44 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/com.github.proto-openapi.spec.v2@v1.0+protobuf" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.17.3 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/06ad960" -H "Authorization: Basic YWRxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2lm" 'https://<IP>/openapi/v2?timeout=32s'
I0302 15:57:33.767657      44 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://<IP>/openapi/v2?timeout=32s 403 Forbidden in 173 milliseconds
```

The user which should be used, as long as I understand it, was created by applying this yaml via kubectl:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:  
  name: gitlab-managed-apps
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: gitlab-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: gitlab-admin
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
```

There's also a service account within the GCP project with `Kubernetes Engine Developer` permissions.

As such, I've no idea why there's still no user defined/associated.
I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several tries, I found out that I mixed something up with the contexts.
I looked at the `KUBECONFIG` file when I realized the miss-configuration.

The wrong context which was used for the communication with Kubernetes lead to the issue described above.

You can follow the description from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56580804/4375900) to check if you use the right context.

Here's what I did to solve the problem:

1. I checked the config file:

   - `kubectl config view`

I noticed that the setting of current-context points to the wrong context!

2. Then I set the context which was intended to use:

   - `kubectl config get-contexts`
   - `kubectl config set-context NAME`
   - `kubectl config use-context CONTEXT_NAME`

Here you can find a [cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/), which I find very helpful.