# Permission denied using kubectl but able to run helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am facing permission denied errors when using kubectl for all commands, be get pods or apply, but I am able to use helm and login with k9s to perform destructive actions. I am using the same context for all of these actions.

```
kubectl get nodes 
# error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)

kubectl apply -f some-manifest.yaml
# error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Does anyone have a hint as to why this is happening or what to look further into?  I am using a managed k8s on Vultr, a smaller cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that this is a "kubernetes context" problem

Check the solution here: [helm and kubectl context mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570319/helm-and-kubectl-context-mismatch)

Solution for k9s can be found here: https://k9scli.io/topics/commands/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what specifically the issue was but I rebuilt my `.kube/config` file slowly with all my contexts and it ended up working again.

Very strange though that helm worked and kubectl didn't though...