# Helm: how set Kubernetes cluster Endpoint

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube, helm3

I have two containers:

- one hosting the cluster (minikube)
- one where the deployment is triggered (with helm)

When running elm install I get

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused
```

This is clear, because my cluster is running on a different host). How/Where can I set the Kubernetes Cluster IP address? When I run helm install my app should be deployed on the remote cluster.

Comment: It normally uses the `$HOME/.kube/config` file, the file mentioned in the `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable, or the other standard Kubernetes configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with

```
helm --kube-context=
```

The steps to create the context are desribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570319/helm-and-kubectl-context-mismatch)